# Whenever refresh a page it is navigating to initialRoute using go_route flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using go_router: ^9.0.3 for routing in my flutter application, but when I reload a screen ,it navigating back to initial route.Initially I  set the route as static,which fixed the issue.However ,i need to pass an auth value,so i created a function.
.After created that function the same issue is happening again.

```
static late GoRouter gr2 ;
  static GoRouter returnRouter(isAuth) {
    gr2 = GoRouter(
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: AppRouteConstant.splashRoute,
            path: '/',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return  MaterialPage(
                  child:SplashWidget(isTokenValid: isAuth,key:  UniqueKey(),)
              );
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: AppRouteConstant.loginRoute,
            path: '/login',
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Login_Screen(  key: UniqueKey(),);
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: AppRouteConstant.welcomeRoute,
            path: '/welcome',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return const MaterialPage(child: WelcomeScreen());
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: AppRouteConstant.navigationWidget,
            path: '/navigationWidget',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return const MaterialPage(child: NavigationWidget());
            },
          ),
        
        
          GoRoute(
            name: AppRouteConstant.homeRoute,
            path: '/home',

            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return const MaterialPage(
                  child:HomeScreen()
                //     SplashWidget(
                //   isTokenValid: isAuth,
                // )
              );
            },

          ),
          
        ],
        errorPageBuilder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialPage(
              child: Scaffold(
            body: Text(state.error.toString()),
          ));
        },
        redirect: (context, state) {
       
         

        }
        );
     return gr2;
  }
```